# Can you help me with Codable error in Alamofire response?

Tags: json, swift, parsing, alamofire, codable

I get recently problem with parsing response with Codable. I am rewriting older app to Swift.

I found problem. I have this response for example on server:

`{
  "object": {
     "key1": "key"
     "key2": "key"
     "key3": "key"
  }
}`

I call Alamofire request to get response.

Response from it I decode to JSON with $0.responseJSON. When I print it, I have this in console:

`{
  object: {
     key1: "key"
     "key2": "key"
     key3: "key"
  }
}`

When I am trying use Codable on this response. It fails, it can't find required value.
Basically, it can decode "key2" key. I think It is connected to quotas, because I test in different keys in JSON.

Can give me a tip what to change in app side?

Sorry for this simple overview.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? You should show your `Codable` class.

Comment: While you're editing to provide that [mcve], please also edit your title to something meaningful. *Can you help me* is not useful - it's clear you need help, or you wouldn't be posting here. Your title should describe a problem or ask a question in a way that will be future to future readers here who are scanning a list of search results. Your current title just repeats information that is already in the tags after the plea for help.

Comment: @redak105 please check your key1 and key3 types. it should be of type `string`. i can guess your app is expecting for string.

Answer (score -1):

You can create two Codable structures or Codable class on it. One for Root object and second for your Object.

Like below is my classes for your response.

**Root class:**

```
class RootClass: Codable {
    var object: Object?
}
```

**Object class:**

```
class Object: Codable {
    var key1 : String?
    var key2 : String?
    var key3 : String?
}
```

so, now in your data response you can doing like:

```
do {
    // Here data is the data you get from response.
    let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(RootClass.self, from: data)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

And I suggest you to verify your JSON it must be like this:

```
{
    "object": {
        "key1": "key",
        "key2": "key",
        "key3": "key"
    }
}
```

Hope this will work for you.